# How to translate the buttons in qmessagebox?

Tags: c++, qt, messagebox, language-translation

I have a `QMessageBox` like this:

```
QMessageBox::question(this, tr("Sure want to quit?"), 
    tr("Sure to quit?"), QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
```

How could I translate the Yes/No word? since there is no place to place a `tr()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979062/qt-dynamic-translation-of-dialog-windows

Answer (score 20):

Sorry, I'm late, but there is a best way of solving your issue.

The right way is not to manually translate those strings. Qt already includes translations in the `translation` folder.

The idea is to load the translations (`qm` files) included in Qt.

I'd like to show you a code to get the message translated according to your locale:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTranslator>
#include <QLibraryInfo>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTranslator qtTranslator;
    if (qtTranslator.load(QLocale::system(),
                "qt", "_",
                QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath)))
    {
        qDebug() << "qtTranslator ok";
        app.installTranslator(&qtTranslator);
    }

    QTranslator qtBaseTranslator;
    if (qtBaseTranslator.load("qtbase_" + QLocale::system().name(),
                QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath)))
    {
        qDebug() << "qtBaseTranslator ok";
        app.installTranslator(&qtBaseTranslator);
    }

    QMessageBox::question(0, QObject::tr("Sure want to quit?"), QObject::tr("Sure to quit?"), QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Notes:

- You can load a different locate creating a new QLocale object and setting it using `void QLocale::setDefault(const QLocale & locale)`. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313896/changing-locale-in-qt).
- I'm loading `qt_*.qm` and `qtbase_*.qm` because since Qt 5.3 the translations are splited in different files. In fact, for `QMessageBox` the translated strings are in `qtbase_*.qm`. Loading both is a good practice. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850108/translations-of-qmessagebox-not-work-in-qt5-3). There are more `qm` files like `qtquickcontrols_*.qm` or `qtmultimedia_*qm`. Load the required ones according to your requirements.
- Maybe you can find the text you're trying to translate is not translated yet by Qt. In this case, I recommend you to upgrade the Qt version to check if the translation exists in the most recent version or code yourself the change. Some useful links: [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Localization) and [here](https://github.com/qtproject/qttranslations).

Comment: Have you tested that the translations work in the final build? The Qt translation files are included? Because I have the same issue. It works in debug and release but not in the final build. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074603/how-can-i-include-c-qt-5-9-1-msvc2015-translations-qm-files-qt-framework-qm-f

Comment: @Mihai Generally, the release configuration has the final installation files. What's the difference between release and final in your case?

Comment: My final release did not contain the qt qm files which I referenced in code using qtTranslator->load("qt_" + language, QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath)); which gives a path from qt framework. I didn't add them in my project.

Answer (score 16):

This is the way to do that:

```
QMessageBox messageBox(QMessageBox::Question,
            tr("Sure want to quit?"),
            tr("Sure to quit?"),
            QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No,
            this);
    messageBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::Yes, tr("Yes"));
    messageBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::No, tr("No"));
```

And to show the message:

```
messageBox.exec();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But my problem is that in my application, there are a lot of message box. Is there any way I can get the button translated in batch instead of doing this setButtonText for each messageBox?

Comment: You will have to change QMessageBox::question to QMessageBox messageBox in code everywhere. In translations you will need to set Yes and No only where it will be necessary, there should a few places only.

Comment: The problem with QMessageBox::question is that it is unlocalizable so you have to replace it

Comment: You can create your own wrapper, which will be inherited from `QMessageBox` and call `setButtonText()` methods inside of it.

Comment: Yes, you can replace the QMessageBox::question to the calls of your own wrapper

Comment: This is completely unnecessary. Qt is already fully localized.

Answer (score 5):

**update**:
I found in *D:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\Src\qttranslations\translations\qtbase_**.ts* already has the QPlatformTheme's translation srouce file (Unfortunately, there is no *qtbase_zh_CN.ts*), you can also copy a qtbase_**.ts and modify it immediately. 
If you are a Chinese like me, thanks to **[wisaly(github)](https://github.com/wisaly/qtbase_zh)**, he has already translated the qtbase to Chinese, and here is **[my fork](https://github.com/doufu3344/qtbase_zh)** on github.

---

After reading the Qt source code, I solved this issue.
(My Qt's version is Qt 5.7.0, and installed in *C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0* with Src)

Open the *C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\Src\qtbase\src\gui\gui.pro* and insert a line like below to generate a Chinese translation file:

```
TRANSLATIONS    +=  gui_zh.ts
```

Open the *gui.pro* project with Qt Creator and use **lupdate** to generate a new cute's translation source file named *gui_zh.ts.*

Open the *qui_zh.ts* using Linguist and translate the **QPlatformTheme** item. Here only translated “&Yes” as a example:
[image]

After translated, use **lrelease** to generate a binary translation file (*gui_zh.qm*).

Lastly, load the translations files (*gui_zh.qm*) to your QApplication, the button's text of QMessageBox will be ok.

My results are：

```
QMessageBox::information(this,
    QString("警告"),
    QString("测试文本"),
    QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No
);
```

[image]

By the way, you can also use this method to sovle the right contextmenu's transtions issues of some QWidgets like QTextEdit by add translations to *C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\Src\qtbase\src\widgets\widgets.pro*.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a special QMessageBoxEx class for this issue.

```
// init once your button texts
QMessageBoxEx::setCustomTextForButton(QMessageBox::Yes, "Да");
QMessageBoxEx::setCustomTextForButton(QMessageBox::No, "Нет");

// example usage
if (QMessageBoxEx::question(this, "Внимание", "Ошибка", QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No) == QMessageBox::Yes)
{
   // OK
}

// header

class QMessageBoxEx : public QMessageBox
{
private:

    static QMap<QMessageBox::StandardButton, QString> m_customButtonNames;

protected:

    static void setCustomTextForButtons(QMessageBoxEx &msgBox);

public:

    QMessageBoxEx(QWidget *parent);

    static void setCustomTextForButton(QMessageBox::StandardButton button, const QString &text);

    static QMessageBox::StandardButton critical(QWidget *parent, const QString &title, const QString &text, QMessageBox::StandardButtons buttons = QMessageBox::Ok, QMessageBox::StandardButton defaultButton = NoButton);
    static QMessageBox::StandardButton information(QWidget *parent, const QString &title, const QString &text, QMessageBox::StandardButtons buttons = QMessageBox::Ok, QMessageBox::StandardButton defaultButton = NoButton);
    static QMessageBox::StandardButton question(QWidget *parent, const QString &title, const QString &text, QMessageBox::StandardButtons buttons = QMessageBox::StandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No), QMessageBox::StandardButton defaultButton = QMessageBox::NoButton);
    static QMessageBox::StandardButton warning(QWidget *parent, const QString &title, const QString &text, QMessageBox::StandardButtons buttons = QMessageBox::Ok, QMessageBox::StandardButton defaultButton = NoButton);

};

// implementation

QMap<QMessageBox::StandardButton, QString> QMessageBoxEx::m_customButtonNames;

void QMessageBoxEx::setCustomTextForButton(QMessageBox::StandardButton button, const QString &text)
{
    if (m_customButtonNames.contains(button))
        m_customButtonNames.erase(m_customButtonNames.find(button));

    m_customButtonNames[button] = text;
}

void QMessageBoxEx::setCustomTextForButtons(QMessageBoxEx &msgBox)
{
    if (m_customButtonNames.size())
    {
        QMessageBox::StandardButtons buttons = msgBox.standardButtons();

        for (auto button : m_customButtonNames.keys())
        {
            if (buttons & button)
            {
                msgBox.setButtonText(button, m_customButtonNames[button]);
            }
        }
    }
}

QMessageBox::StandardButton QMessageBoxEx::critical(QWidget *parent, const QString &title, const QString &text, QMessageBox::StandardButtons buttons, QMessageBox::StandardButton defaultButton)
{
    QMessageBoxEx msgBox(parent);

    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Critical);
    msgBox.setWindowTitle(title);
    msgBox.setText(text);
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(buttons);
    msgBox.setDefaultButton(defaultButton);

    setCustomTextForButtons(msgBox);

    return (QMessageBox::StandardButton)msgBox.exec();
}

QMessageBox::StandardButton QMessageBoxEx::information(QWidget *parent, const QString &title, const QString &text, QMessageBox::StandardButtons buttons, QMessageBox::StandardButton defaultButton)
{
    QMessageBoxEx msgBox(parent);

    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Information);
    msgBox.setWindowTitle(title);
    msgBox.setText(text);
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(buttons);
    msgBox.setDefaultButton(defaultButton);

    setCustomTextForButtons(msgBox);

    return (QMessageBox::StandardButton)msgBox.exec();
}

QMessageBox::StandardButton QMessageBoxEx::question(QWidget *parent, const QString &title, const QString &text, QMessageBox::StandardButtons buttons, QMessageBox::StandardButton defaultButton)
{
    QMessageBoxEx msgBox(parent);

    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Question);
    msgBox.setWindowTitle(title);
    msgBox.setText(text);
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(buttons);
    msgBox.setDefaultButton(defaultButton);

    setCustomTextForButtons(msgBox);

    return (QMessageBox::StandardButton)msgBox.exec();
}

QMessageBox::StandardButton QMessageBoxEx::warning(QWidget *parent, const QString &title, const QString &text, QMessageBox::StandardButtons buttons, QMessageBox::StandardButton defaultButton)
{
    QMessageBoxEx msgBox(parent);

    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
    msgBox.setWindowTitle(title);
    msgBox.setText(text);
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(buttons);
    msgBox.setDefaultButton(defaultButton);

    setCustomTextForButtons(msgBox);

    return (QMessageBox::StandardButton)msgBox.exec();
}

QMessageBoxEx::QMessageBoxEx(QWidget *parent) : QMessageBox(parent)
{

}
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/kleuter/81a75a50e60a75aa0370a66ededc0c31

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to do this. These texts *are* localized in Qt's own localization files. You need to provide, and perhaps also load, Qt's localizations within your application.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working with many languages. I had the problems with French though I loaded all the localizations and I checked their files, translations missed

Comment: Also Qt localization is for limited number of languages I believe

Comment: @demonplus Nothing prevents you or anyone else from fixing up these translation files. Sounds trivial compared to the pain of messing up with every messagebox instance.

Comment: Agree with you that this is another way to go. You need to load qt language file in your application.

Comment: @demonplus It's the *only* way to go. Anything else is sheer insanity.

Comment: @KubaOber Totally agree. I've answered with a better solution, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You can translate Text "Save" in this case to different language by clicking translatable check box as below.

[image]

Which language is depending on the locale you load when loading the application. You can do this as follows

`QApplication app(argc, argv);`
`//loading my_translation_pt file`
`QString file= app.applicationDirPath() +"/my_translation_pt";`
`QTranslator translator;`
`translator.load(file);`
`//Setting the translator to the QApp`
`app.installTranslator(&translator);`

sample my_translation_pt file is attached below

[image]


you can encode the tranlation using 
c:\Qt\4.7.1\bin>lrelease.exe :\temp\my_translation_pt

Answer (score 0):

I do this this way, no need to create a subclass:

```
int Feedback = QMessageBox::information(this, "Info title", "Message to user.", "MyLocal_OK_text", "MyLocal_Cancel_text");

if(Feedback == 1){
  //MyLocal_Cancel_text chosen actions
   }
```

Comment: Could you explain how the translation is done here? Or are you suggesting one should just put the message in the target language manually?

Comment: The result is the number of the button in the order it has been specified after message text. So pressing the first button in 
QMessageBox::information(this, "Info title", "Message to user.", "Yes", "No") 
will return button will return 0 for Yes and 1 for No

Comment: This answer is off-topic.