# How to internationalize the buttons on a QMessageBox::warning?

Tags: internationalization, qmessagebox

I am trying to internationalize (English/French) QMessageBox::warning - and almost completely succeeded - in the following way:

*

```
...
QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;
reply = QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("System will be affected"),
QString(tr("%1 %2\n\nDo you wish to proceed?)).arg(m_disFrontVariants.getTitleFor(m_disFrontVariantName)).arg(warningMsg), **QMessageBox::Cancel|QMessageBox::Yes, QMessageBox::Cancel**);
if(reply != QMessageBox::Yes) {
   return false;
}
...
```

*

This results in a half-translation that looks like this:

[image: Half-baked Internationalized QMessageBox::warning]

So while I can very well internationalize the title and the text, I haven't been able to find a way to do so for the StandardButtons. And note that the result of the warning box creation is used as decision value.

Is there a way to achieve a fully translated QMessageBox::warning? Or must I replace it with a custom QMessageBox warning box? If the latter then how can I still use the yellow warning icon?

Answer (score 0):

This is well answered here:

[How to translate the buttons in qmessagebox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533019/how-to-translate-the-buttons-in-qmessagebox)

I used the 2nd solution provided and it worked very well.