# how it works QMessageBox

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Please tell me where I made a mistake? My code:

```
void deletetable::on_pb_dell_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox messageBox(QMessageBox::Question,
            tr("Sure want to quit?"), tr("Sure to quit?"), QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No, this);
    messageBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::Yes, tr("Yes"));
    messageBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::No, tr("No"));
    messageBox.exec();
    if (messageBox.QMessageBox::Yes) {
        emit deleteYear(year);
        close();
    } else {
        
    }
}
```

my function `deleteYear(year)` works in any condition, i.e. if I click "No", the function will still work.
I took an example from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31533126/13023647

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
messageBox.QMessageBox::Yes
```

Is just accessing the `enum` `Yes`, which is going to evaluate the same each time.

You want to capture the actual response from the question and query that, such as:

```
auto response = QMessageBox::question(this, "Save", "Do you wish to save?", QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard | QMessageBox::Cancel);


if (response == QMessageBox::Save) { ... }
```

See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#question here for more info.

---

To keep the same format above you can get the response with `messageBox.result()` e.g.

```
if (messageBox.result() == QMessageBox::Yes) { ... }
```

Comment: Great example, thank you. But the fact is that I need to translate the standard "Yes" and "No" buttons into another language, so I use the above construction.

Comment: @AlexRebell You can take the return value from the `exec()` call and query that e.g.  `auto response = messageBox.exec();`  and `if (response == QMessageBox::Yes) {...}`

Comment: Super! What you need, thank you very much! Update your answer,I'll mark it solved.

Comment: Note that apparently Qt 6.2 has marked `QMessageBox::question` obsolete.