# How to add translation files to Qt

Tags: qt, qt5

The following questions focus on the same issue, which is translation some Qt inner Words:

[Title：Qt: how to translate the buttons in qmessagebox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533019/title-qt-how-to-translate-the-buttons-in-qmessagebox)

[Translations of QMessageBox not work in Qt5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850108/translations-of-qmessagebox-not-work-in-qt5-3)

[Qt Dynamic translation of dialog windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979062/qt-dynamic-translation-of-dialog-windows)

I searched in here and found (at C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\Tools\QtCreator\share\qtcreator\translations) there is no translation file for brazil/portuguese.

How can I create and contribute one of this files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR Use Qt Linguist to create translation files.

The whole process of application translation:

1. At first you have to prepare your app for translation by marking strings which you want to translate: [Writing Source Code for Translation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html)
2. Translate the application with Qt Linguist: [Qt Linguist Manual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlinguist-index.html)
3. Load translation files with application: [Hello tr() Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlinguist-hellotr-example.html) or [How to create a multi language application](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application)

Answer (score 1):

Add translations to the project

At first you have to prepare your app for translation by marking strings which you want to translate:

> tr()

In your qmake project file, the following variable TRANSLATIONS has to be added and must contain all language files you want to create initially.

> TRANSLATIONS = languages/TranslationExample_en.ts  >languages/TranslationExample_de.ts

You will find lupdate and lrelese int the QT Creater at: Extras-> extern -> linguist

By calling lupdate

> lupdate -verbose TranslationExample.pro
>   You create the language files (.ts), which you translate by using the tool Qt >Linguist.
>   linguist languages/TranslationExample_en.ts languages/TranslationExample_de.ts

After doing this, you call lrelease to create the binary language files (.qm):

> lrelease TranslationExample.pro

You will find this manual as a long version :

> http://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application